# Encoding for Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, categorical-data, encoding, categorical-encoding

I have a `CSV` file with salary information and other columns.

[image]

I am trying to transform some of these columns into proper values, for a `LinearRegression` and a `SGDRegressor`, or some other. Because, I don't think that the `LinearRegression` in `sklearn` can handle the data bits **as is**.

**Data:**

- **607** records
- **Numerical columns:** *year*, *salary*, *salary in USD*
- **Categorical columns:** *experience*, *type*, *residence*, *currency*, *remote work*, *company location*, and *company size*.
- **Target:** *salary in USD*

**Encoding:**

```
# Import neccessary encoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Encoding of categorical data
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

# Extract columns
columns = data[['Experience', 'Type', 'Residence', 'Remote work', 'Company location', 'Company size']]
```

**Questions:**

- How to group any data within the categories (to avoid duplicates)?
- Is `OneHotEncoder` the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: What's your question?  Your post gives a lot of background info but it's not clear what you need help with

Comment: Just an observation: you have missed `currency` in your extract columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments:

- You should not group any data even if there are duplicates, because this would distort the distribution of the values (features and target).
- `OneHotEncoder` should be used on the categorical features only. Even with those, mind that values which are too rare should usually be removed or replaced in order to avoid overfitting.
- Some algorithms work better with numerical features scaled.
- Linear regression is unlikely to work well with some complex data in my opinion. Personally I like to try decision tree regression for this kind of mixed dataset.